# Xamarin Android progress dialog crashes in Android version below lollipop on show method

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, progressdialog, crash-reports

```
loginButton.click += delegate
{
 ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(Application.Context, 
 Resource.Style.CustomAlertDialogStyle);
 progress.SetMessage(" Please wait...");
 progress.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.next);
 progress.SetCancelable(false);
 progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
 progress.SetInverseBackgroundForced(true);
 progress.Indeterminate = true;     
 progress.SetIndeterminateDrawable(GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Header));
 progress.Show();               
}
```

Here is my code for the Progress dialog, What I want is that the dialog appears when I log in as I have to call a lot of data from 
service side and it works properly in higher android version but the problem is when I use it on a device with Android version KitKat or below the 
Application crashes when the compiler reaches progress.show(); and I'm unable to understand why as I am new to Xamarin Android.

Comment: What is the full Exception/Stacktrace?

Comment: "An unhandled exception occured." is all i get No explanation nothing

Comment: Review your logcat output, there will be more to it...

Comment: it says unable to find class referenced in signature @SushiHangover

Comment: if your device is attached while running, use the `Device Log` pad: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/ Or use the cmd line: `adb logcat` : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: Yes i did that and this what it said "unable to find class referenced in signature" @SushiHangover And it also gives me some kind of path to a folder

Comment: Add the entire error to your question, there will be multiple lines associated to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer myself by doing the things below

```
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    loginButton.Click += async delegate
        {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, string.Empty, string.Empty);
            dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Loader);
    .
    .
    .

           }
```

loader.xml

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/layout_root"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#105499"
      android:orientation="vertical"
    >
     <ProgressBar
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loader_Anime"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Loader_anime.xml

```
         <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item
             android:drawable="@drawable/Oxy_top"
             android:duration="50"/>

            <item
              android:drawable="@drawable/Oxy_right"
              android:duration="50"/>


            <item
             android:drawable="@drawable/Oxy_bottom"
             android:duration="50"/>


           <item
             android:drawable="@drawable/Oxy_left" 
             android:duration="50"/>
            </animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why this error raised but create `ProgressDialog`  on Click event is bad idea

move all this code to onCreate() method

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(Application.Context, 
 Resource.Style.CustomAlertDialogStyle);
 progress.SetMessage(" Please wait...");
 progress.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.next);
 progress.SetCancelable(false);
 progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
 progress.SetInverseBackgroundForced(true);
 progress.Indeterminate = true;     
 progress.SetIndeterminateDrawable(GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.OxyHeader));
```

and just show progress in click method

```
if(progress != null){
progress.Show();  
}
```